# Why is my button firing twice?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CButton as part of a CDialog screen.  Everything works fine, but after I reinitialize a hardware device, when I click anywhere on the screen (even outside the dialog) the event for the CButton in question fires.  I've run through the code in debugger mode, and the app literally thinks the button in question is being pressed.  Thing is, its NOT being pressed.  I've experimented with clearing the message pump, but that didn't seem to help.  If you need code, let me know and I'll see what I can drum up without giving away how our app works.  I get the feeling this is an edge case that others have run into and know how to solve without code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the "event for the CButton" is indeed mapped to the button, and not (by mistake) to the dialog itself?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou that is NOT happening.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: have you tried running spy++ to see the messages and whatnot? Have you checked that the initialization routines dont call post message (or whatever) to click that button? perhaps there is some overlap in the control ID?

Comment: @jhbh I haven't run spy+, but that won't show the messages, only the handle to the windows that are currently running.  I don't need that info.  I checked the init routines.  Could you elaborate on the overlap in the control ID?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So...what's the secret hardware device whose driver triggers this?

Comment: Simplify the message map of your dialog code until the problem goes away. This will of course not solve your problem, but it may help you to find the cause..

Comment: *"without giving away how our app works"* - That's the opposite of what you need to do, to get any help. If we cannot see, how your application works, we cannot help you solve your bug.

Comment: @DanG if you right click on a window in spy++ you will get a context menu with a "messages" option that will show all the windows messages recieved by the window eg wm_mousemove etc. As for control IDs there are a few things that might happen, in your message map you accidentally mapped a message to the wrong control/message handler, or perhaps two controls have the same value eg IDC_BTN1 and IDC_BTN2 are both #defined as 2543

Comment: @jhbh Thanks.  I'll try your suggestion.